# what is broadcom's strataXGS architecture?

Tags: broadcom

what is Broadcom's strataXGS architecture ? Any references?  I refereed the internet and Broadcom site there is no detailed explanation ? What is new in this architecture ?

Comment: Got the answer, please remove it out of hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a sales PDF that might answer some questions:

- http://www.broadcom.com/docs/features/StrataXGS_Trident_II_presentation.pdf

Here are some links to white papers:

- http://www.broadcom.com/products/features/cloud_scale_net.php

Some key features<sup>[1](http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/BRCM/0x0x593658/243d982b-98ce-40bf-9979-f443b596c1d8/BRCM_News_2012_8_27_Infrastructure_and_Networking.pdf)</sup>:

- Enables unprecedented 10/40GbE single chip switch configurations
- 100+ 10GbE ports with flexibility to support up to 32 40GbE ports
- First integrated switch delivers NVGRE and VXLAN L2oL3 transit and gateway switch technologies
- Supports industry's highest equal cost multipathing-based fat-tree networking scale on a single chip
- Greater FCoE network scale enabling true LAN/SAN convergence — up to 4X increase in forwarding entries
- High port density with direct attach to SFP+/QSFP modules and KR Backplanes
- Integrated IEEE 1588 1-step timing solution

  - Delivers 40 percent reduction in bill of material costs and 30 percent better phase accuracy

Comment: http://www.broadcom.com/products/features/cloud_scale_net.php has everuthing I was looking for . Thanks :)

Comment: not sure how to reopen, once it is reopened i would reward the bounty to ur id.

Comment: No worries it automatically assigned the bounty to me when the time expired. Thanks :)